# SSH asking me for passphrase which doesn't have any passphrase

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

I have generated the keys in Ubuntu 14.04 system using the following commands to use with ssh.

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
 openssl rsa -in id_rsa -outform pem > pk_rsa.pem
 openssl rsa -in pk_rsa.pem -pubout -out my_key.pem
```

I have copied the my_key.pem to my local which is OSX. Trying to ssh into the Ubuntu using the below command

```
 ssh -v -i ./my_key.pem ubuntu@192.168.113.137 
 OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: Connecting to 192.168.113.137 [192.168.113.137] port 22.
 debug1: Connection established.
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
 debug1: identity file ./ubu14.pem type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file ./ubu14.pem-cert type -1
 debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
 debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
 debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.113.137:22 as 'ubuntu'
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
 debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
 debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
 debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
 debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
 debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:KDokJiZiQ9ZflT5Jm5B8krQ8XgsEEgUjQjg+h6C4Gqo
 debug1: Host '192.168.113.137' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
 debug1: Found key in /Users/macdev/.ssh/known_hosts:11
 debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
 debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Trying private key: ./my_key.pem
 Enter passphrase for key './my_key.pem': 
 debug1: Next authentication method: password
 mahesh@192.168.113.137's password:
```

Is there way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are conflating two different technologies, `openssh` and `openssl`.  It appears you need only the former.

As you have already created an ssh key pair, you just need to copy the public key to the server you intend to ssh to.  The correct way to do this is:

```
$ ssh-copy-id username@<server-ip>
```

Replace *username* and <*server-ip*> with the user and IP address of your server.

Comment: i want to use the ssh-key generated in the server just like the pem file which we get  from amazon ec2 instances so that I can login to server from different machines without password using the pem file.

Comment: @mahesh it won't prompt you for a password unless you set a password when creating the key.

Comment: I havn't set the password i left with empty passphrase while generating

Comment: @mahesh, okay did you `ssh-copy-id username@<server-ip>`?

Comment: No I haven't done

Comment: @mahesh, you need to do that to copy the key to the server.  Then the next time you `ssh username@<server-ip>` you won't be prompted for a password.